# Is 'such' a pronoun in "Such were the extremes of emotion that Mr. Ramsay excited in his children’s breasts"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, relative-clauses

I have a question about the passage.  Is the word "such" a pronoun and what does it refer to?

> Had there been an axe handy, a poker, or any weapon that would have gashed a hole in his father’s breast and killed him, there and then, James would have seized it. **Such** were the extremes of emotion that Mr. Ramsay excited in his children’s breasts by his mere presence; standing, as now, lean as a knife, narrow as the blade of one, grinning sarcastically, not only with the pleasure of disillusioning his son and casting ridicule upon his wife, who was ten thousand times better in every way than he was (James thought), but also with some secret conceit at his own accuracy of judgement.

from the part 1 of the novel "To the Lighthouse" by Virginia Woolf.

https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/w/woolf/virginia/w91t/part1.html

Comment: **such** (meaning "of the kind previously mentioned or implied or described") is a predicate adjective. The sentence in which it appears uses inversion: The extremes of emotion that Mr Ramsay excited in his children...were such. That is, they were so extreme as to be murderous. See the sentence that immediately precedes the sentence in question.

Comment: I've eliminated the  questions where you have understood correctly or where the answer would require literary interpretation.

Comment: @Li Virginia Woolf does not write in easy English. I'd be surprised if you didn't have multiple questions about many of her sentences. I usually do! When you ask a question here, though, you have to focus on one specific thing about a sentence. You did a great job of including the context and providing a link to the source. (Most people who ask questions here don't.) You should always do that in every question you ask that quotes material that you didn't write, even if you post several questions about  the same material.

Comment: I [moved the previous discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45798/discussion-on-question-by-li-xiaodong-is-such-a-pronoun-in-such-were-the-extr) now that the question has been improved.